# Is there any way to add additional lines to Vuetifys list?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm working on my own social network now, and I'm using Vuetify to design it. I use cards to display posts and list to display comments. The thing is that for scenario where user writes really long comment, maximum of 3 lines is not enough. Is there any way to add more lines to list item? Also, I would prefer not to use cards for comments because they don't allow me to easily add author of post.

Comment: you can use v-list's slots and define your own layout and styles

Comment: Alright, I decided to use a card. I just used 2 text rows, where 1 holds avatar and name, and the second one holds content of the comment.

Comment: @DawidCyron - do you mind sharing the snippet of code for it